# How can I implement this type of data structure?

Tags: c++, class, vector, data-structures, computer-science

I have this assignment to create a class Car that uses vector to hold Car objects with data that holds id (int), make (string), and model (string). What I do not understand are these instructions here:

- make up 5 cars and save them into a file: cars.data
- load these cars' info from the file, initialize 5 Car objects, place them into the vector
- if new cars are added by user, they should be appended to the cars.data file when exiting the program
- design a menu-based user interface that allows following operations:
  -- search by id
  -- search by make
  -- search by model
  -- add a new car (new car id cannot be same as existing ones)
  -- delete an existing car by id
  -- list all cars
  -- exit the program

Mainly how to create a .data file and code it to where I use the file in the main.cpp. My teacher supplied us with an example; however, I would like to see multiple ways that can implement this to understand this problem better.

Comment: If that is the entire assignment, then it looks like the structure of the data file is up to you. That gives you great flexibility as you can tailor the format to how you decide to read the file. (Often the format is specified, which can make the code that reads the file more complex than it would be otherwise.)

Comment: Besides, the best resource for clarifying a confusing assignment often is the person who gave you the assignment in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

You can moreover use the concept of shared memory(which you might have learned in Subject Operating system) and implement your project using it.
It is also famous by the name "Producer Consumer Problem".

Producer process, on each iteration, takes details of a car (name, enroll no, section, age etc.) from the user and puts this data as an item into the shared buffer.
The consumer process on the other hand, on each of its iteration, retrieves a data item from the buffer and saves it in a CSV file(or cars.data in your case) on the disk, where the fields (id (int), make (string), and model (string) etc.) of a data-item are stored in comma-separated format (as usually stored in CSV).

Comment: It’s really not clear to me how turning the original problem into a producer-consumer implementation adds any value or clarity.

Comment: But it does add more value to the project for example, one can add the data from producer program, while at the same time in other terminal one can access menu-based interface in the producer file.